# Java keytool commands not runnig from Process builder

Tags: java, processbuilder, keytool

I am trying to run keytool commands from ProcesBuilder of JAVA but it is failing with below error:

"Illegal option:   -genkeypairKey and Certificate Management ToolCommands: -certreq            Generates a certificate request -changealias
Changes an entry's alias -delete             Deletes an entry -exportcert         Exports certificate -genkeypair
Generates a key pair -genseckey          Generates a secret key -gencert            Generates certificate from a certificate request -importcert
Imports a certificate or a certificate chain -importpass         Imports a password -importkeystore     Imports one or all entries from another keystore 
-keypasswd          Changes the key password of an entry -list               Lists entries in a keystore -printcert
Prints the content of a certificate -printcertreq       Prints the content of a certificate request -printcrl
Prints the content of a CRL file -storepasswd        Changes the store password of a keystoreUse 
"keytool -command_name -help" for usage of command_name"

Below is the Code snippet for the same:

```
public void testName() throws Exception {
    {
        String[] commands = { "keytool ", " -genkeypair  ", " -keyalg ", " RSA ", " -keysize ", " 2048 ",
                " -alias ", " rootkey ", " -dname ", "DNAME_INFORMATION", " -keystore ", " .keystore ",
                " -storetype ", " PKCS12 ", " -storepass ", " pass ", " -keypass ", " pass" };
        ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        // You can set up your work directory
        probuilder.directory(new File(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "\\bin"));

        Process process = probuilder.start();

        // Read out dir output
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        final StringBuilder commandStr = new StringBuilder();
        for (final String command : commands) {
            commandStr.append(command);
            commandStr.append(" ");
        }
        System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n", commandStr.toString());
        is = process.getErrorStream();
        if (null != is) {
            isr = new InputStreamReader(is, Charsets.UTF_8);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        }
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (null != br) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sbuffer.append(line);
            }
        }
        // If sbuffer contains some value then error has occured.
        // Wait to get exit value
        try {
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If we run the same command from %JAVA_HOME%/bin directory (i.e. cmd) then it creates the .keystore file with out any error.

Command: 
keytool -genkeypair  -keyalg   RSA  -keysize  2048  -alias  rootkey  -dname  "DNAME_INFORMATION"  -keystore  .keystore  -storetype  PKCS12  -storepass  pass  -keypass  pass

Please advise if anyone have faced any such issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove the spaces around your arguments.

```
String[] commands = { "keytool ", "-genkeypair", "-keyalg", "RSA", "-keysize", "2048",
    "-alias", "rootkey", "-dname", "DNAME_INFORMATION", "-keystore", ".keystore",
    "-storetype", "PKCS12", "-storepass", "pass", "-keypass", "pass" };
```

Btw, you cann access a key store directly, see the [KeyStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) class.

Comment: Thnaks a lot.. After removing the spaces it is working fine.. :)